# startMonitoringForRegion event is not triggering in ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ibeacon

I was trying to monitor beacon in background.

For that I'm using `startMonitoringForRegion` event but the event is not triggered and didn't called the delegate method  `didEnterRegion` and `didExitRegion`.

Using:

1. Cordva
2. Ionic Framework

My Code snippet:

```
$cordovaBeacon.startMonitoringForRegion(
    $cordovaBeacon.createBeaconRegion(
        ("estimote", "12458118-34AE-11a6-AC61-9E71128CAE77"));

$rootScope.$on("$cordovaBeacon:didEnterRegion", function(event, pluginResult) {
    console.log("ibeacondidEnterRegion")
});

$rootScope.$on("$cordovaBeacon:didExitRegion", function(event, pluginResult) {
    console.log("ibeacondidExitRegion")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things to check:

- Can you detect the beacon using an off-the-shelf app on the same device?
- Does your app have location permission enabled (Needed for iOS and Android 6+)?  Go to settings for the app to see.

Comment: Location permission is already enabled.. To access only public devices..

Comment: But is the location permission enabled for the app (separate from the global setting)?  What OS versions is this?